# Username & Password in JDBC Connection URL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I was using a SQuirrel SQL Client to connect & browse my oracle database servers. I have given the credentials in the connection URL itself. But it still prompts for the username and password. Does it really required to provide additional username/password while establishing  connection. Won't it take it from the connection URL?

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@my.oracle.server.domain.com:1521:DBName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Won't it take it from the connection
>   URL?

I think No

You need to enter usrename & password.

Check: h[ttp://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/user-manual/quick_start.html#howtoconnect](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/user-manual/quick_start.html#howtoconnect)

section `Connecting`

Comment: Depends on the implementation. Drivers should be able to handle the connection string "jdbc:oracle:thin:@${HOST}:${PORT}:${SID}?user=${UID}&password=${PWD}"

Answer (score 15):

Thin driver
Oracle's JDBC Thin driver uses Java sockets to connect directly to Oracle. It provides its own TCP/IP version of Oracle's SQL*Net protocol. Because it is 100% Java, this driver is platform independent and can also run from a Web Browser (applets).
There are 2 URL syntax, old syntax which will only work with SID and the new one with Oracle service name.

Old syntax

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID

New syntax

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE

On new syntax SERVICE may be a oracle service name or a SID.

**There are also some drivers that support a URL syntax which allow to put Oracle user id and password in URL.**

> jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@[HOST][:PORT]:SID
>
> jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE

source: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Comment: Here works withou `//` like: `jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/SERVICE`

Answer (score 10):

Refer to this link, it will help you.

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-parameters

For example, if you want to include username & password in the Postgres connection string.

```
jdbc:postgresql://postgres-10.4.cluster:5432/default?user=postgres&password=postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I [have](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) [seen](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Oracle-JDBC-Driver-Connection-URL.html), support for passing the username/password in the JDBC URL is inconsistent across Oracle JDBC Drivers.