Upon trying to run my code, I get this problem:
enter image description here
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
    at DemoClass.main(DemoClass.java:33)

I already added mysql connector jar file in the libraries. What else should i do to get out of these excetions?

Make sure you are specifying username and password correctly.

Just to get things going, try putting the username and password in the connection URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547224/username-password-in-jdbc-connection-url

The “Access denied for user ‘root’@‘localhost’ (using password: NO)” error occurs when trying to connect to a MySQL database using the root user without providing a password
Try to specify the password for the root user in your connection string.
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_database?user=root&password=your_password";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);



NonRegisteringDriver.connect

When this error is shown it means to reinstall your MYSQL Database. You have to do a fresh install because it is corrupted as a result of a bad install. Hope this helps!

That's not an error. It's simply a frame in the call stack.

How do you know that for sure?

That message comes from the middle of the stack, that's how. When you read a stack trace, you're looking primarily at the first and last lines, and any line that starts "Caused by..." Randomly selecting a frame from the middle of the stack isn't going to tell you much.
